# Maven compilation error try-with-resources

Tags: java, maven, java-8, compilation

I have the following configuration in my system:

Apache Maven 3.5.2
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_162, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-20-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

When I compile (using maven) my project that have Try-with-Resources I get the following error:

```
/path/driver.java:[29,13] try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources)
```

I have tryed to add the flag   -source 7 but thats not the way to solve the problem cause it give me this other error:

```
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] The specified user settings file does not exist: /path/ource
```

I have search in internet for the first error and I didn't found anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option already suggested by @Ravindra.
Another option is to add properties.

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

See [maven-compiler-plugin refeerence](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the Java 8 language features (-source 1.8) and also want the compiled classes to be compatible with JVM 1.8 (-target 1.8), you can either add the two following properties, which are the default property names for the plugin parameters:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  [...]
</project>
```

or configure the plugin directly:

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Check out this [article](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) for further details. However `try-with-resources` was introduced in JDK 1.7 (internal) version.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part, add the following lines to the POM to set language level

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

After adding those lines you can successfully build your jar, although when you run it your jar will give a no main manifest attribute error.

This can either be fixed by running like `java -cp app.jar` `com.somepackage.SomeClass`

or to correct this and make an executable jar, make your pom look like

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>fully.qualified.main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```